# POC scenario idea for TFS 2010

Tags: tfs

I am going to present POC of TFS (Team Foundation Server) 2010 in front of non-technical staff. Are there any sets of scenario idea that highlighting the power of TFS 2010 that can be easily demonstrated and understood by non-technical audiences?

The POC scope is about banking (a small local bank)

Since my knowledge about TFS is very limited, I want some of your suggestions.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Are there any other similar questions to this that have more answers?

Answer (score 1):

Work items! Especially the the Bug and Risk ones. Demo that you can have a task with an associated risk and that you can report on the progress / status of work items. Bug tracking is also a good thing to demo

The project portal is also a good thing to demo, it shows outstanding work and burndown chats. You can also manage work items from your web browser so non devs can manage the work.

If your company use MS project (or Excel, or both) you could demo the MS Project integration for managing work items.

You could also try demoing some of the reporting, Build reports show nice graphs that get the non techies excited. (code quality, unit test coverage)

Notice I haven't talked about Source Control. you probably want to show it, but from a non techie point of view, it's something they aren't going to get. Don't go in to too much detail. Just use it to show associating a work item with a checkin and then lead in to the Automated builds, which then lead in to the build reports.

Comment: Great POC ideas. both applicable to banking and generic scope.